# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<any>>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I’m working on a http request. I've faced problem previously which my object shows [object promise] in the URL request. So i had await the return of the Promise of the object which is my `user` variable.

But I'm now getting an error

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type `Promise<Observable<any>>`.

I also googled this and have done necessary changes but the outcome is the same.

this is my code of the http request:

```
async getUserFromStorage():Promise<any>{
    return await this.storage.get('currentUser');
}

async getUserOrder()
{
  const user = await this.getUserFromStorage();
  var url="https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder/GetUserOrder?email=";
  console.log(url+user);
  return this.http.get(url+user).map(res=>res.json());
}
```

This is the code which is failing:

```
    public getOrders(){
    this.getUserOrder()
    .subscribe(data =>{                //HERE
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
      {
        this.orders.push(data[i]);
      }
    })
    return this.orders;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
const getUserOrder = await this.getUserOrder();
getUserOrder.subscribe(data => {
...
```

The reason is that you are missing `await`

---

Like @Brendan B mention there's also no reason for the `async` on `getUserOrder` method actually, sense you are returning an Observable. You can also delete the `async` keyword from this method and it'll work.

Comment: If this works for you can you also accept answer? Thanks :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

async functions don't return promises, you are trying to subscribe to a promise.

Try removing the async from `async getUserOrder()`